# How do I view user names stored in app_data

Tags: asp.net

I can't login to my application because I don't know my username. How do I figure it out?

My connection string is:     `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL server management studio to do it:

1. Make a backup of your .mdf and .ldf files (SQL Server can modify these files, such as upgrading them to a newer version and render them unusable by your application)
2. Connect to your localhost (.) using Windows Authentication in SQL Server management studio
3. Right click on the databases node in the Object Explorer window
4. Click Attach
5. Click Add
6. Navigate to your projects app_data folder and select ASPNETDB.MDF
7. Click OK
8. Click OK
9. Find your database in object explorer and open a new query window
10. Execute this query to list all the users: `select * from aspnet_users` your username will be in that dataset.
11. Detach the database, delete the .mdf and .ldf files and restore them from the backup you made.

Comment: I think you can also use the built-in Server Explorer within Visual Studio to accomplish the same.